# Play VLC as Wallpaper / enable DirectX / My Preferences do NOT match the many hits on Google

Tags: webcam, vlc, wallpaper

I'm trying to play videos as wallpaper with VLC.  Countless hits on Google show preferences dialog boxes that don't match what I have.

Thinking of marking this as Duplicate?  Please be very careful, there are a LOT of old, obsolete posts on the web.  Just because you find the same question, doesn't mean the answer is still valid.

I think I also may need to enable directX output, but none of the screenshots from Google match my Preferences for doing that either.

I'm running the latest MacOS Ventura 13.0 on an Intel iMac from 2017

VLC, I don't see a version, but I just downloaded it (2/19/2023)

Context: What I'm really trying to do is use a webcam as a live wallpaper.  All the solutions I've found online or in the App Store don't work.  I'd like to also ask if anybody can suggest an alternative tool for doing this, but I think getting specific software recommendations isn't OK on here?  I already found how to view from a webcam in VLC, so that half of the equation is solved.

Comment: That’s not how dupes work.  The question is still the same and a newer answer can be added. You’re also asking for a software recommendation which is off topic here.  Also, DirectX is a Windows technology; it’s unclear why you’re referencing it here

Comment: Part of the reason you find many Google hits that don't seem to work is that VLC on Win & Mac are two quite different beasts. The prefs are different & in different places. Macs have never used DirectX either.